# dbUnit FlatXmlDataSet vs. XmlDataSet

Tags: dbunit

I have been using XmlDataSet in my project for dbUnit test data.
 
I am finding it really difficult to populate the test data in this format. 
I am thinking of using FlatXmlDataSet. With this I will be able to create test data in database, export it and use it in my project using IDatabaseConnection.createDataSet() 
I would like to know if any such exporting mechanism is available for XmlDataSet
Also, are there any drawbacks or advantages of using FlatXmlDataSet?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
IDatabaseConnection dbConn = new DatabaseDataSourceConnection(this.dataSource);
IDataSet actual = dbConn.createDataSet();
XmlDataSet.write(actual, new FileOutputStream("full.xml"))
```

Hope that helps.